# How to show controller in Ionic only first time the app is opened?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have seen a lot on Google: tours, walk-throughs and introduction pages for `Ionic` and `Angular`, but I can't trace how it's **just shown solely the first the app is ever opened (and after that, it won't shown again, unless you remove the app)**.

So what I want to do is to show a view / controller / page I've made just once and only when the app is opened the first time. On the second visit, I don't want the people to see it any more.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you not check for a value in Local Storage when your app is opened? If the value is not set or false, you show the page and set the value for next time, otherwise redirect immediately to a new route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller use

```
if(localStorage.getItem['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
    localStorage.setItem['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
    $state.go('onetime.view'); 
}
else{
    $state.go('your.route');
}
```

So when your app loads first time, Your localstorage will be null. So it will route you to your first time page and also set the localstorage, So that when you load the app second time the condition will be not satisfied.

OR

```
if(localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
    localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
    $state.go('onetime.view'); 
}
else{
    $state.go('your.route');
}
```

Comment: If localstorage is null the first time, then how will it enter the if block? Won't it go to the else block?

Comment: @papakias thanks for pointing out the error. It should've been != where i had specified == . Now it's proper

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it doesn't seem like it's working. Where exactly do I put this? I have this in the general controller, for example: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("somepage"); 
Should I combine it or place it beneath? In which controller do I put it?

Comment: @Siyah you have to put this in the controller of the view which is gonna load first. `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/somepage');` . So when the first page loads, this code is gonna execute and the states are gonna change accordingly

Comment: Also you can specify your first time page in `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/somepage');` and then route to other pages. Hope this works

Comment: But, does that mean that I can get rid of: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/somepage');, if I use your solution or not? Can you show me a snippet where you use it too? I don't get it, still.

Comment: @Siyah Sorry i was away for couple of days. You need `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/somepage');` coz this will be your landing page. You have to check the localstorage in your same controller.

Comment: Thanks mate! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Gururaj, could you help me out? This solution leads to a glitch before you see the actual page. It shows you the other page for 1 second or something before it directs you to the other. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Cordova Local Storage native Plugin. Go to below URL to know how to add and use plugin into your project.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Once you're familiar with that, then use this logic in constructor on app.components.ts of your project.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => 
{
    // get property value
    this.storage.get('introShown').then((result) => 
    {
        // If it is set, then skip that page
        if(result){
          this.rootPage = 'Tabs';
        }
        // Otherwise if property is not set, then show that page for once and then set property to true
        else {
          this.rootPage = 'Intro';
          this.storage.set('introShown', true);
        }

      });

    });
```